# What happens to pthread_t after pthread_create?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix

I'm wondering just what happens to t after i run this code.

```
pthread_t t = 0;
pthread_create(&t,NULL,&thread_function, NULL);
```

So the question is basically, what value gets put in t after pthread_create.

Thanks, for any answer!

Comment: Is the freely available documentation unclear?   How the two answers got upvotes I cannot understand:(

Answer (score 2):

It's the ID of the thread you just created. You need it if you want to refer to the thread again.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> Before returning, a successful call to pthread_create() stores the ID of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by `t`; this identifier is used to refer to the thread in subsequent calls to other pthreads functions.